# postfix resend mails after removing from blacklist

Tags: postfix

I have a mail server which was listed by Spamhaus and hence emails were not going out, I have removed the server from the list now my question is would postfix resend the emails which were not being sent out as the IP was listed?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the messages are still in the mailq then they will be sent out. If not, then the users will need to resend.

They would still be in the mailq if the other mailserver returned a soft error (4.x.x) and the `maximal_queue_lifetime` has not expired, five days by default.

They will not be in the queue if the other mail server returned a hard error (5.x.x) or the `maximal_queue_lifetime`  has expired.

Comment: I checked the mailq and mostly the error was 544 "refused to talk to me" so I guess we lost these emails?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
postqueue -f
```

To flush the postfix queue - this will immediately try to redeliver all the messages in the queue. They will eventually try n their own but you can speed up the process with this command.

> ```
>   -f     Flush the queue: attempt to deliver all queued mail.
>
>           This  option  implements the traditional "sendmail -q" command,
>           by contacting the Postfix qmgr(8) daemon.
>
>           Warning: flushing undeliverable mail frequently will result  in
>           poor delivery performance of all other mail.
> ```